# how to get text document content with the google docs api

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I trying to get the content of a text document with the google docs api, this is how i get the url to export the document like text

```
  MediaContent mc = (MediaContent) entry.getContent();
  String UrlForDownload = mc.getUri()+"&exportFormat=txt&format=txt";
```

but don't know how to get the content in java,

hope someone can help thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try fllowing code:

```
MediaContent mc = new MediaContent();
mc.setUri(UrlForDownload);
MediaSource ms = docsService.getMedia(mc);
InputStream in = ms.getInputStream();
```